# Forms authentication failed for the request

Tags: asp.net, webforms, forms-authentication

I have a web application using cookieless forms authentication. Every day my event log has a ton of 4005 error codes (Forms authentication failed for the request). I believe this is happening because users are bookmarking pages while they are logged in so when they revisit the forms ticket in the url has expired, atleast this is the only scenario I can trigger in testing.

My question is it possible to disable logging for this 4005 code ? its filling up my event log

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question, and I'm not even familiar with ASP. But if, just like for example PHPSESSID and jsessionid, this "forms ticket in the url" is actually a session id that is also added to the URL for *anonymous* visitors, then maybe search engines can cause this error as well? And if so: doesn't that break your search scores?

Comment: No, because the search engine never login

Comment: So (unlike PHPSESSID and jsessionid) this "forms ticket in the url" is only used for visitors who have logged in, not for anonymous users? If it is also used for anonymous users, then the search engine will see such URLs as well (though they may be smart enough to remove it from the URL). As a side note: Safari 4 will take snapshot previews of webpages, and update those every now and then. That might yield the same result.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the error so it does not appear in the log

```
'in global.asax
Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
     ' Code that runs when an unhandled error occurs
     Dim lastError As Exception = Server.GetLastError()
     ' Must be a better way, just can remember how, you will get the idea.
     If lastError.Message.Contains("Forms authentication failed for the request") Then
         'do nothing
         Server.ClearError()            
     End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use cookies, its a much better solution than cookieless mode because your users will get to use bookmarks, which they'd surely expect to be able to do, and your error log will not be filled with errors. Its also less vulnerable to session hijacking.